# Python/BeautifulSoup Parsing HTML Fractions

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, beautifulsoup

**Questions**

1. Why does is the output in the final two cases BOTH unicode, but in one case it shows the fraction, and in the other it shows some other code representing the fraction?
2. What is the cleanest way for me to go from the fraction to a decimal (-1.75)?

**Background**

I am using `BeautifulSoup` and `Python` to read some `HTML.`  The `HTML` outputs fractions.  Below is the python code I am using to test this problem, and the resulting output.  In the below code I have

```
print type(c[0])
print c[0]
print type(c[0].get_text())
print c[0].get_text()
print type(re.split(" ", c[0].get_text())[0])
print re.split(" ", c[0].get_text())
```

and this outputs:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<b>-1¾ -101</b>
<type 'unicode'>
-1¾ -101
<type 'unicode'>
[u'-1\xbe\xa0-101']
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's get the easy part of your question out of the way first:

When you print a list, the `repr` of the contents is used to represent the items in the list. So since

```
re.split(" ", c[0].get_text())
```

is a list, the print statement prints the [repr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html#module-repr) of the `unicode` element in the list.

```
In [63]: x = u'-1\xbe\xa0-101'

In [64]: print(x)
-1¾ -101

In [65]: repr(x)
Out[65]: "u'-1\\xbe\\xa0-101'"
```

---

Now for the interesting part: Some unicode code points have names.
For example,

```
In [60]: import unicodedata as ud

In [61]: ud.name(u'\xbe')
Out[61]: 'VULGAR FRACTION THREE QUARTERS'
```

In fact, we can search through all the unicode characters for those with names which match the pattern `'FRACTION (\w+) (\w+)'`:

```
import unicodedata as ud
import re

numerator = {
    'ONE':1,
    'TWO':2,
    'THREE':3,
    'FOUR':4,
    'FIVE':5,
    'SIX':6,
    'SEVEN':7,
    'EIGHT':8,
    'NINE':9,
    'ZERO':0,
    }

denominator = {
    'QUARTER':4,
    'HALF':2,
    'SEVENTH':7,
    'NINTH':9,
    'THIRD':3,
    'FIFTH':5,
    'SIXTH':6,
    'EIGHTH':8,
    'SIXTEENTH':16
    }

fraction = {}
for num in range(0x110000):
    s = unichr(num)
    try:
        name = ud.name(s)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    match = re.search('FRACTION ({n}) ({d})'.format(
        n = '|'.join(numerator.keys()),
        d = '|'.join(denominator.keys()),
        ) , name)
    if match:
        fraction[num] = unicode(
           float(numerator[match.group(1)])/denominator[match.group(2)]).lstrip('0')
print(fraction)
```

Thus we now have a `dict` named `fraction` which maps unicode code points to `unicode` decimal representations of the fractions.

```
{8585: u'.0', 43056: u'.25', 43057: u'.5', 43058: u'.75', 43059: u'.0625', 43060: u'.125', 43061: u'.1875', 188: u'.25', 189: u'.5', 190: u'.75', 8528: u'.142857142857', 8529: u'.111111111111', 8531: u'.333333333333', 8532: u'.666666666667', 8533: u'.2', 8534: u'.4', 8535: u'.6', 8536: u'.8', 8537: u'.166666666667', 8538: u'.833333333333', 8539: u'.125', 8540: u'.375', 8541: u'.625', 8542: u'.875', 69245: u'.333333333333', 3443: u'.25', 3444: u'.5', 3445: u'.75', 69243: u'.5', 69244: u'.25', 11517: u'.5', 69246: u'.666666666667'}
```

Now you can translate `u'-1\xbe\xa0-101'` like this:

```
text = u'-1\xbe\xa0-101'
print(text.translate(fraction))
```

yields

```
-1.75 -101
```

---

So the short answer is:

```
fraction = {8585: u'.0', 43056: u'.25', 43057: u'.5', 43058: u'.75', 43059: u'.0625', 43060: u'.125', 43061: u'.1875', 188: u'.25', 189: u'.5', 190: u'.75', 8528: u'.142857142857', 8529: u'.111111111111', 8531: u'.333333333333', 8532: u'.666666666667', 8533: u'.2', 8534: u'.4', 8535: u'.6', 8536: u'.8', 8537: u'.166666666667', 8538: u'.833333333333', 8539: u'.125', 8540: u'.375', 8541: u'.625', 8542: u'.875', 69245: u'.333333333333', 3443: u'.25', 3444: u'.5', 3445: u'.75', 69243: u'.5', 69244: u'.25', 11517: u'.5', 69246: u'.666666666667'}
text = c[0].get_text()
text = text.translate(fraction)
parts = map(float, text.split())
print(parts)
```

yields

```
[-1.75, -101.0]
```

Note that in the future it is possible that more fractions are assigned unicode code points. It is also possible that the name of the unicode code point does not match the pattern `'FRACTION ({n}) ({d})'` that I used to generate the `fraction` dict. So my solution is somewhat fragile and may need to be updated in the future.

Comment: unutbu thanks so much for response.  I am surprised there is not a library or something already created for this problem.  I am just n00bie programmer so it is taking me a while to go through your answer which is cool I am learning from your programming techniques here.

Comment: If you have any questions, I'll try to elaborate.